# Extra space from top after call from app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `tableView` to show contact number's and some relevant info, where the tap over `tableviewCell` enables my user to call that concerning person from app.

Making call using below code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel: 9999999999"]];
```

**Problem:**

> Getting an extra space from top when user ends call and automatically backed the to app, see screenshots below.

**Before call:**

[image]

**After call backed by system to app:**

[image]

How can i solve please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: are you using uinavigationbar or is it your custom view ?

Comment: @JenJose, its a `uinavigationbar`.

Answer (score 1):

In your viewcontroller, implement `UIBarPositioningDelegate` and add below method inside.

```
func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
  return .TopAttached
}
```

Or, add this on ViewWillAppear

```
var frame: CGRect = (self.navigationController?.view.frame)!
frame.origin.y = 0
self.navigationController?.view.frame = frame
```

Comment: hi. it's confusing sometimes to understand actually what's causing the problem, when causes are multiple. Try another code I append.

Comment: sure, i will revert you back soon.

Comment: I tried the updated solution, unfortunately not working. Actually the `viewWillApprear` method not getting called when user backed from call to app.

Comment: try to add in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: doesn't help any more, please be practical before you suggest to apply.

Comment: I had a same problem before and it solved by my first code.

Comment: Vaibhav please don't take it personally, I had given answer and suggestions based on my practical. If it's not working for you, you can take back your plus point.

Comment: i dont and i knew very well, but i regards everyone. It would be nice if you can try this with objective c.